# Is desktop linux allowed/prevalent here?

Tags: discussion

I use Linux on all the computers in my home. Is this a good place to ask questions about Linux on a desktop, or should I ask on a different site?

Answer (score 6):

This is the right place. If you check the first section of the FAQ, [What can I ask here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), it lists a number of categories of questions that are on-topic. The first is:

> - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server

I certainly don't know how *many* people here use Linux on a desktop, but it's probably a majority; server-oriented people tend to hang out on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: so do you use linux on the desktop

Comment: wow so my question to a site that i can ask question on. HUM

Comment: @saras: Yes most of the regulars around here use linux on the desktop. Just ask your questions and see how it goes.

Comment: @saras one caveat, if your question is very Ubuntu-centric try on http://askubuntu.com